# Customized validation for AuthorizeAttribute keeps the process running

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following customized validator :

```
public class CAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //if ajax request set status code and end responcse
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true; 
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(/*some data*/);                        
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }

}
```

and the following Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [CAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Comment(Comment comment_obj)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            this.tblSomthing.comments.Add(comment_obj);
            this.db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return /*some view*/
    }
```

why when the validator fails the action is executed and the DB record is saved but the response is correct (the one that is set in the validator)
I just want to stop the execution of the action if the validator fails.

Answer (score 0):

You know that an action needs to return a view in order the user sees some form of output? Using `Response.Write` or `Response.End` in a controller does nothing.

Anyway what you have there is an attribute, not a validator. 
If it were a validator it'd be inside the model used in the view, applied to a property.

Comment: thats correct Sir, but when we use the `[Authorize]` attribute the action dose not execute right? thats what i'm trying to do, and for the response => the `Response.Write` returned the correct data instead of the view.

Comment: If the action shouldnt execute why are you testing Model.IsValid inside it? That's contradictory to what you're saying. Again, don't use Response.Write. If something works that doesn't mean it's good practice. The problem is that you don't understand what you're doing. If you explain more about what you want to do i can help you maybe.

Comment: first of all, thanks alot for your time, what I want is simple i want to return simple data (json) when the user is not authorized to an action and terminate the action ... to be more clear . the action is as you can see `comment` the comments feature is not available for none logged in users . its ajax call i want to return the json data when the user is not authorized ... and for the IsValid this attribute is call to check the following (min/max length /required ...) , i hope its more clear now ... thanks